# Trying to get cursor with coordinate display within a pyqtgraph plotwidget in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, cursor-position

I'm trying to add a readout of the cursor position in a pqytplot plotwidget in PyQt5. I found this code which does what I want, but in a stand-alone window all within one program file:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

#generate layout
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
win.addItem(label)
p1 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0)

data1 = [n**2 for n in range(100)]
p1.plot(data1, pen="r")

#cross hair
vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
p1.addItem(vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
p1.addItem(hLine, ignoreBounds=True)


def mouseMoved(evt):
    pos = evt[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
    if p1.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
        mousePoint = p1.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        index = int(mousePoint.x())
        if index > 0 and index < len(data1):
            label.setText("<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x=%0.1f,   <span style='color: red'>y1=%0.1f</span>" % (mousePoint.x(), data1[index]))
        vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
        hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())


proxy = pg.SignalProxy(p1.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseMoved)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The problem I'm running in to is figuring out how to implement something like this with my GUI - where I will have to pass reference to the plotwidget to the mouseMoved function.  In the example above, the mousemoved function has access to hline, vline and p1, but in my code it won't - I need to be able to pass those through.  But I have no idea how to do that.

I've tried to replicate this issue with the smallest amount of code possible.  First here's a simple UI file for the GUI, called CursorLayout.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1167</width>
    <height>443</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_16">
        <property name="sizeConstraint">
         <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
        </property>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="startbutton">
              <property name="sizePolicy">
               <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
                <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                <verstretch>0</verstretch>
               </sizepolicy>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Plot</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
        <item>
         <widget class="PlotWidget" name="plotWidget" native="true">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>300</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3"/>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_17">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="exitbutton">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Exit</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">pyqtgraph</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The main program is this:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from initGUI import connecttolayout, setinitialview


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("CursorLayout.ui", self)  #load GUI layout file created with QtDesigner
        connecttolayout(self)  # connect code to elements in UI file
        setinitialview(self)  # set initial view (button/label visibility, default values, etc)
        self.show()


    def clickedstartButton(self):  #action if start button clicked
        self.plotWidget.clear()
        plotx = range(100)
        ploty = [number**2 for number in plotx]
        thisline = self.plotWidget.plot(plotx, ploty, pen='r')
        QApplication.processEvents()


    def clickedexitButton(self):
        self.close()


app=QApplication([])
UIWindow=UI()
app.exec()
```

with file containing code to set up the gui, initGUI.py (not necessarily how you would do this, but this is to mimic the file structure of my larger program):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
import pyqtgraph as pg

def connecttolayout(self):  #connect GUI elements to elements in UI file
    self.startButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "startbutton")
    self.exitButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "exitbutton")
    self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedstartButton)
    self.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedexitButton)

def mouseMoved(evt):
    pos = evt[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
    if self.plotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
        mousePoint = self.plotWidget.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        index = int(mousePoint.x())
        #if index > 0 and index < len(data1):
        if index > 0 and index < self.MFmax:
            self.cursorlabel.setText("<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x=%0.1f,   <span style='color: red'>y=%0.1f</span>" % (
            mousePoint.x(), mousePoint.y()))
        self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
        self.hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())


def setinitialview(self): #set initial view to pvst view and clear plot window
    #set plot initial configuration
    self.plotWidget.setBackground('w')
    self.plotWidget.setLabels(left=('Pressure', 'Torr'))
    self.plotWidget.setLabel('left',color='black',size=30)
    self.plotWidget.setLabels(bottom=('Time', 's'))
    self.plotWidget.setLabel('bottom',color='black',size=30)
    self.plotWidget.clear()

    # cross hair
    self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
    self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
    self.plotWidget.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
    self.plotWidget.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)
    self.cursorlabel = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
    proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.plotWidget.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseMoved)
```

I'm actually surprised my attempt doesn't cause an error - pressing the plot button does create a plot, but it definitely doesn't create the cursor in the graph in the GUI.

How do I get the necessary info passed to the mouseMoved function?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few little errors that will make your program fail:

- The `mouseMoved()` function has to be inside your widget class because it needs the `evt` argument, which is generated in the widget.
- The `self.MFmax` variable/constant is not created anywhere
- In this line:

  ```
  mousePoint = self.plotWidget.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
  ```

  The `PlotWidget` object doesn't have the `vb` attribute. It is a `PlotItem`'s attribute, then you should change that line to this:

  ```
  mousePoint = self.plotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
  ```
- Pyqtgraph recommends [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/labelitem.html?highlight=Note:) to use `TextItem` instead of `LabelItem`, to display text inside a scaled view, because of its scaling size.

Now, with that said and reorganizing your code to be more legible, here is my solution to your code (you only need the `UI` file and this script):

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, uic

ui_file = uic.loadUiType("CursorLayout.ui")[0]

class UI(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_file):
    def __init__(self):
        ## Inherit the QMainWindow and ui_file classes
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        ui_file.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        ## Create aditional widgets
        self.plot_item = self.plotWidget.plot()
        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
        self.cursorlabel = pg.TextItem(anchor=(-1,10))
        ## Build the rest of the GUI
        self.format_plot()
        ## data
        self.plotx = range(100)
        self.ploty = [number**2 for number in self.plotx]        
        ## Connect signals to actions
        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.clickedstartButton)
        self.exitbutton.clicked.connect(self.clickedexitButton)
        self.plotWidget.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouseMoved)
    
    ## OVERWRITE the mouseMoved action:
    def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt
        if self.plotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            mousePoint = self.plotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            index = int(mousePoint.x())
            if index > 0 and index < len(self.plotx):
            # if index > 0 and index < self.MFmax:
                self.cursorlabel.setHtml(
                    "<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x={:0.1f}, \
                     <span style='color: red'>y={:0.1f}</span>".format(
                mousePoint.x(), mousePoint.y()))
            self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
            self.hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())
  
    def clickedstartButton(self):  #action if start button clicked
        self.plot_item.setData(self.plotx, self.ploty, pen='r')
        self.plotWidget.addItem(self.cursorlabel)

    def clickedexitButton(self):
        self.close()
    
    def format_plot(self):
        self.plotWidget.setBackground('w')
        self.plotWidget.setLabels(left=('Pressure', 'Torr'))
        self.plotWidget.setLabel('left',color='black',size=30)
        self.plotWidget.setLabels(bottom=('Time', 's'))
        self.plotWidget.setLabel('bottom',color='black',size=30)
        self.plotWidget.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.plotWidget.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code above will make the "crosshair" (the `hline` and `vline`) to follow your mouse and displaying the coordinates of that position, like this:

[image]

If you want the "crosshair" to track the points in the curve based on the x-axis position of your cursor, you can change the `mouseMoved()` function to this:

```
def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt
        if self.plotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            mousePoint = self.plotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            mx = np.array([abs(i-mousePoint.x()) for i in self.plotx])
            index = mx.argmin()
            if index >= 0 and index < len(self.plotx):
                self.cursorlabel.setHtml(
                    "<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x={:0.1f}, \
                     <span style='color: red'>y={:0.1f}</span>".format(
                     self.plotx[index], self.ploty[index])
                     )
            self.vLine.setPos(self.plotx[index])
            self.hLine.setPos(self.ploty[index])
```

And this will be the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Performance of mx calculation in mouseMoved can be largly improved in order to get a faster response of the cursor:

```
def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt
        if self.plotWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            mousePoint = self.plotWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            mx = abs(np.ones(len(self.plotx))*mousePoint.x() - self.plotx)
            index = mx.argmin()
            if index >= 0 and index < len(self.plotx):
                self.cursorlabel.setHtml(
                    "<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x={:0.1f}, \
                     <span style='color: red'>y={:0.1f}</span>".format(
                     self.plotx[index], self.ploty[index])
                     )
            self.vLine.setPos(self.plotx[index])
            self.hLine.setPos(self.ploty[index])
```

Comment: hi nicely done, I would be interested in a way to be able to navigate scatter plots, where I've more than one y value for the same x value, your def mouseMoved(self, evt): won't work in this case any place I should look for ?